# IOS Managing the Keyboard - Move UIScrollView Content up

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I am using the example in the IOS Developer Library for managing the keyboard.
[Text, Web and Edition Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)

I have created a view using the IB. Its a simple UI that has a UIScrollView, UITextView, UIButton, and a UITextField. I placed the UIScrollView on my view and then added all the other controls as children of this scrollview. The scrollview is exposed to the viewcontroller via a IBOutlet "scrollView".

The follow code executes with the user sets focus to the textField but I never see a scrollbar appear and the scrollbar's contents are not moved. Should I be able to see the scrollbar by default? Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

```
  -(void) keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)aNotification{

    NSDictionary * info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your application might not need or want this behavior.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, activeField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height);
        [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Again, I'm taking this code directly from the IOS Programming guide in the link. The UI layout looks like a basic chat window. I would like to move the "input" field up while the soft keyboard is visible. Thanks!
**Update**

It seems that I needed to add some padding to actually see the controls located at the bottom of the scrollview.

```
 CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, (activeField.frame.origin.y - kbSize.height) + 10.0);
```

How come I don't see scrollbars?

Comment: Your question title suggests you're asking "How do I move my scrollcontent up?" while your question is actually "Why are the scrollbar indicators not visible?" or "How to make the scrollbar indicators visible?". You might want to edit that.

Answer (score 1):

IF YOU HAVE PARENT VIEW AS SCROLL THEN JUST USE : UITextFielddelegate  and set the methods

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField == self.txtUserName)
    {
       [self.txtPassword becomeFirstResponder];
    } 
    else if(textField == self.txtPassword){
       [self.txtPassword resignFirstResponder];
        CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
       [scrView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
       [textField resignFirstResponder];
   }
    return YES;
}

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   if (textField == self.txtUserName)
   {
       CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, 80);
       [scrView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
   }
   if (textField == self.txtPassword)
   {
      CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, 135);
     [scrView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Scrollbars should show up only on user interaction. That's not the case here since your programmatically setting the inset of your scrollview.

If you want to show the scroll bars, i believe `UIScrollView` defines a `flashScrollIndicators` method, that should show the scroll bars.